# How can I make my drop down menu keyboard accessible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, accessibility

I have a drop down menu that I need i to be keyboard accessible, but don't know how to do it.  In my css I have the a:focus on all the links.  I'm assuming using onfocus in the javascript/jquery would be the best instead of hard coding the tab key into the javascript, correct?  If so, what would I do to the code to use the focus selector?  The menu needs to drop when someone tabs into it, then when they tab off of it (or maybe they could press the escape key since there are over 40 links) it needs to shut (needs to be just like it does when mousingover/mousingout).  [Example Menu](http://okfocused.com/cu)

```
if (ie === "1") {
if ($(window).width() > 949) {

$.fn.pause=function(a){$(this).stop().animate({dummy:1},a);return this};
function mouseleft(){$("#buttonbar").triggerHandler("mouseleave")}
$(document).ready(function()
  {$("#buttonbar").mouseenter(function(){$(this).stop().pause(160).animate({height:"12.7em"},400,"easeOutQuart")}).mouseleave(function(){$(this).stop().pause(160).animate({height:"2.2em"},400,"easeOutQuart")});});$(function(){$("#accordion").accordion({fillSpace:!0,icons:{header:"accordion-header",headerSelected:"accordion-headerselected"}})});
if((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i))) {
    $("#buttonbar li").bind('touchstart', function(){
        console.log("touch started");
    });
$("#buttonbar li").bind('touchend', function(){
        console.log("touch ended");
    });
}
else {
 $("#accordion").accordion({active:false});
}
}

function showElement(d){
  var s=document.getElementById(d).style;
  if ($(window).width() < 950) {
    if (s.display != "block" ) { s.display = "block"; } else { s.display = "none"; }
  if ($(window).width() > 949) {
    if (s.display != "block" ) { s.display = "block"; } 
  }
}
}
function showHide() {
  var s=document.getElementById("buttonbar").style;
  if ($(window).width() > 949) {
    s.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("prospective-links").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("current-links").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("academic-links").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("facstaff-links").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("parent-links").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("alumni-links").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("visitor-links").style.display = "block";
$("#accordion").accordion('destroy');
    $("#buttonbar").unbind('mouseenter');
    $("#buttonbar").unbind('mouseleave');
$.fn.pause=function(a){$(this).stop().animate({dummy:1},a);return this};
function mouseleft(){$("#buttonbar").triggerHandler("mouseleave")}
$(document).ready(function()
  {$("#buttonbar").mouseenter(function(){$(this).stop().pause(160).animate({height:"12.7em"},400,"easeOutQuart")}).mouseleave(function(){$(this).stop().pause(160).animate({height:"2.2em"},400,"easeOutQuart")});});$(function(){$("#accordion").accordion({fillSpace:!0,icons:{header:"accordion-header",headerSelected:"accordion-headerselected"}})});
if((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i))) {
    $("#buttonbar li").bind('touchstart', function(){
        console.log("touch started");
    });
$("#buttonbar li").bind('touchend', function(){
        console.log("touch ended");
    });
}

  }
  else {
    /*$("#accordion").accordion({active:false});*/
    $("#accordion").accordion('destroy');
    $("#buttonbar").unbind('mouseenter');
    $("#buttonbar").unbind('mouseleave');
    $("#buttonbar li").unbind('touchstart');
    $("#buttonbar li").unbind('touchend');

    s.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("prospective-links").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("current-links").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("academic-links").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("facstaff-links").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("parent-links").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("alumni-links").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("visitor-links").style.display = "none";
    /*$("#buttonbar").accordion('destroy');*/

  }

}
$(window).resize(showHide); //Run when resized

jQuery(function($) {
  var path = location.pathname.substring(1);
  $('#nav a[href$="' + path + '"]').addClass('active');
});

// This section makes the skip to anchor links such as the skip to content link work in webkit browsers like Chrome and Safari
(function(linkList,i,URI) {
   if (!!(URI = document.documentURI)) {
        URI = URI.split('#')[0];
      document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
         document.removeEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", arguments.callee, false);
         linkList = document.links;
         for (i in linkList) {
            if (!!linkList[i].hash) {
               if (linkList[i].hash.match(/^#./)) {
                  if ((URI+linkList[i].hash)==linkList[i].href){
                     linkList[i].addEventListener("click", function(e,f,g) {
                        f = document.getElementById(this.hash.slice(1));
                        if (!(g = f.getAttribute('tabIndex'))) f.setAttribute('tabIndex',-1);
                        f.focus();
                        if (!g) f.removeAttribute('tabIndex');
                     }, false);
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }, false);
   }
   return true;
})();
}
else {
function showElement(d){
  var s=document.getElementById(d).style;
  if (s.display != "block" ) { s.display = "block"; } else { s.display = "none"; }
};


};
```

The html is as follows:

```
    <div id="buttonbar">
    <ul id="bar">
  <li id="prospective" class="rightborder"><a>Future Students</a>
    <ul id="prospective-links">
      <li><a href="/admissions">Undergraduate Admissions</a></li>
      <li><a href="/graduate">Graduate Admissions</a></li>
      <li><a href="/admissions/international">International Admissions</a></li>
      <li><a href="/transfer">Transfer Admissions</a></li>
      <li><a href="/advising-center">Academic Advising Center</a></li>
      <li><a href="/financial_aid">Financial Assistance</a></li>
      <li><a href="/info/schedules/tuition">Tuition and Fees</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Test Item 8</a></li>
      <li class="last-item"><a href="/prospective">Go to Future Students</a></li>
    </ul></li>
      <li id="students" class="rightborder"><a href="/current">Current Students</a>
         <ul id="current-links">
            <li><a href="/info/calendars/academic">Academic Calendar</a></li>
            <li><a href="/info/schedules">Enrollment Schedule</a></li>
            <li><a href="/studentservices">Student Life</a></li>
            <li><a href="/housing">Housing</a></li>
            <li><a href="/financial_aid/workstudy.html">On-Campus Jobs</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Bookstore</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Athletics</A></li>
            <li class="fill"><a name="hold">&nbsp;</a></li>
            <li class="last-item"><a href="/current">Go to Current Students</a></li>
         </ul></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: you could look into http://api.jquery.com/keydown/    if you want to add keyboard buttons in it

Comment: It would probably be instructive to look at how other keyboard accessible menu systems do this. Like [superfish](http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/)

Comment: Ok I finally got one of the online editors working with the code.  If anyone would like to test it to see if you can get the menu to drop using the keyboard, I would appreciate it.  

I have put VIDesignz's solution into the html, but I can't make it work.

http://jsbin.com/udobuc/3/

Answer (score 1):

Try using [tabIndex](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/a/tabindex) for the links. (but as steveaz points out they should be already focusable)

```
$('#buttonbar a').attr('tabIndex', 0);
```

For the menu you'd have to add an event as well as the `tabIndex`. `$menu` is the selector for your menu(s), I'm not sure what that is, adjust to your needs:

```
$('#bar').attr('tabIndex', 0)
  .focus(function() { $menu.show(); })
  .keydown(function(e) { e.which == 27 && $menu.hide(); }) // ESC
  .blur(function() { $menu.hide(); });
```

Comment: Really don't recommend mucking with tabindex.

Comment: @steveax: It's save, from SitePoint: _it causes no compatibility issues, and has excellent support across all tested browsers_

Comment: Anytime you change the default tabbing order you're likely to do more damage than good. See [WCAG 2.0 - Focus Order](http://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/navigation-mechanisms-focus-order.html). The links in the menu are already focusable, no need to add anything to them.

Comment: @steveax I see what you are saying...can you offer a solution to help the OP out? I'm not too experienced with tabbing, except on forms and simple stuff like that.

Comment: Yeah, the links should be focusable but I don't see any problem with `tabIndex` for the menu. As long as you use `tabIndex=0` it should be fine.

Comment: Ahh, I think I misunderstood what the OP was asking for. I see now he wants to expose the entire menu. In that case what you suggest (adding tabindex=0) is indeed correct and safe. There should be some content on the item to be focused that lets AT users know what they just focused though, perhaps a heading. This can be visually hidden using CSS.

Comment: @elclanrs, I don't know what my selector is either.  Where do I find that at?  Just a little background about this project.  The menu was already created by someone else and I just came into this project a couple of months ago without any instruction as to how the menu was made/worked.  In case you didn't check out the example, the whole top level drops down (at once) so you can see all the links.

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like...Give your buttonbar a tab index then bind focus/blur functions to show and hide the buttonbar menu

```
$(document).load(function(){

    $('#buttonbar').attr('tabIndex', 0).on({
       focus: function(){
          $("#buttonbar").triggerHandler("mouseenter");
       },
       blur: function(){
          $("#buttonbar").triggerHandler("mouseleave");
       }
    });

});
```

Comment: That is the second problem, I don't know what code needs to do that.  I've tried putting in what I thought it is from the existing code for the mouse, but it doesn't work (which is above).

Comment: @user1666190 I edited my answer, based off the script you posted, I believe this is what you need to make it work.

Comment: Do I put that code at the bottom of the code above or what?  I've tried in the above code and in the head of the html but it still isn't working on my local copy.  It will be tonight before I can update the example from the link above.

Comment: @user1666190 This should go within the `$('document').load();` function, I'll update my answer to reflect this...

Comment: @user1666190 Also, I missed a parenthesis in my code...my bad :(  fixed now!

Comment: I still can't get it to work.  I've updated the example from the link above.

Comment: @user1666190 I am not sure why it is not working.  I modified my code to try again. If this doesn't work, at least partially, I am out of ideas. Put this script right before the body close tag `</body>`